# Merge Cells Based on First Column?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to merge rows A1:D20 based on the values from Column1. I have written a code but it does not stop at the last rows in selection and goes beyond selection by xRows.

```
Sub MergeSameCell() 
Dim Rng As Range, xCell As Range 
Dim xRows As Integer 

Set WorkRng = Application.Selection 
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
Application.DisplayAlerts = False 
xRows = WorkRng.Rows.Count        
For Each Rng In WorkRng.Rows 
    For i = 1 To xRows - 1        
        For j = i + 1 To xRows   
            If Rng.Cells(j, 1).Value = "" Then Exit For
            If Rng.Cells(i, 1).Value <> Rng.Cells(j, 1).Value Then 
                Exit For 
            End If 
        Next 
        WorkRng.Parent.Range(Rng.Cells(i, 1), Rng.Cells(j - 1, 1)).Merge 
        WorkRng.Parent.Range(Rng.Cells(i, 2), Rng.Cells(j - 1, 2)).Merge 
        WorkRng.Parent.Range(Rng.Cells(i, 3), Rng.Cells(j - 1, 3)).Merge 
        WorkRng.Parent.Range(Rng.Cells(i, 4), Rng.Cells(j - 1, 4)).Merge 
        i = j - 1 
    Next 
Next 
Application.DisplayAlerts = True 
Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Cannot test with no usable data, but I think if you remove `For Each Rng In WorkRng.Rows` and the corresponding `Next`, it should work.  (and also probably run faster). You will also need to change `Rng.Cells(i,1)` and similar to refer to the correct cell).  Problem is that when Rng refers to, for example A10:D10, Rng.Cells(1,1) will refer to A10, not A1.

Comment: I added an if condition now its working fine. If Rng.Cells(j, 1).Value = "" Then Exit For

Comment: Hi Ron, Thank you for the suggestion it is indeed running slow so I followed your suggestion and remove For Each and modified sheet reference. It is faster than before.